# How to write update query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
select email, status_id, count(*) from customers group by email, status_id having count(*) > 1;
```

I want to update my all those record that getting above query. I want to update status_id that result comes from above query.

How can I do this?

Please help me.

Comment: First of all, update `status_id` with what? Second, you want to update the same table?

Answer (score 0):

please test this code :

```
UPDATE customers
SET customers.status_id = 
   CASE
     When COUNT(*) >1 Then 'value 1'
     When COUNT(*) <1 Then 'value 2'
     When COUNT(*) = 1 Then 'value 3'
     ELSE 'SARB'
   END  
GROUP BY email, status_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1
```

hope be helpfull